# Cannot sshfs to server over proxycommand on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, openssh, sshfs

I'm trying to connect through sshfs-win to mount a drive over a jumphost.
I can normally connect through ssh but when invoked over sshfs-win it fails.

Also, I can normally mount the jumphost, but not the internal server drive.

```
PS C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin> .\sshfs-win.exe cmd krakenss2:/ Y: -odebug -ologlevel=debug3
SSHFS version 3.5.2
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug3> <-2> <krakenss2> <-s> <sftp>
debug1: Reading configuration data /cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/config
debug1: /cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/config line 29: Applying options for krakenss2
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec "ssh -W int-dev.node:22 jumphost.com -l qqqq -p443"
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\qqqq\\.ssh\\key type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\qqqq\\.ssh\\key-cert type -1
/bin/shdebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
: No such file or directory
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
read: Connection reset by peer
PS C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin>
```

But connecting to the jumphost is ok. I sense the problem is when executing the proxyjump command.

```
PS C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin> .\sshfs-win.exe cmd jump:/ Y: -odebug -ologlevel=debug3
SSHFS version 3.5.2
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug3> <-2> <jump> <-s> <sftp>
debug1: Reading configuration data /cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/config
debug1: /cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for jump
debug2: resolving "jumphost.com" port 443
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to jumphost.com [53] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\qqqq\\.ssh\\key type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\qqqq\\.ssh\\key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to jumphost.com:443 as 'qqq'
debug3: put_host_port: [jumphost.com]:443
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /cygdrive/c/Users/qqqq/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [jumphost.com]:443
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
```